# Augmenting Kalman filter with parameter -- what does the initial value mean?

Tags: prior, kalman-filter, state-space-models

It is a fairly standard trick to augment a Kalman Filter with unknown parameters and to propagate them forth with zero error to estimate them.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what the interpretation is of the initial value and covariance is when I use this trick. I know (books by Harvey or Durbin and Koopman) I could make it diffuse or fixed, but what does it mean for it to be fixed?  Some a priori known mean and covariance? Does this have an interpretation beyond that of a tuning parameter? Something akin to a Bayesian prior? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can write the initial value and variance as the mean and variance of a Gaussian prior on the parameter in a state-space model.

Answer (score 1):

If you include a parameter in the state vector with zero variance and a diffuse prior, you are effectively estimating a fixed effect, much as you would do in an ordinary regression. A non-diffuse prior has the same effect of an ordinary prior on the unknown parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The covariance matrix for the error should be small but not zero, since this may cause convergence problems in the filter (See, for example, Särkkä, 2013, [*Bayesian Filtering and Smoothing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107619289)).

The interpretation of the mean and covariance matrix of the parameter is that they are the prior parameters of the Gaussian in the Bayesian sense. You should put a large covariance if you do not have a good guess for the value of the parameter, otherwise the filter will take much time to converge to the correct value of the parameter (a small covariance matrix will put much weight on your prior guess).

Comment: My understanding was that the Durbin and Koopman treatment performed (as coded in the DLM module) worked well with a partially zero covariance matrix and I've never had obvious problems. No? I agree zero entries leads to non-positive-definiteness and bad performance in a Kalman Filter using the straight equations. Is this a different point?

Comment: What covariance matrix you refer to? The prior or the covariance of errors (aka evolution/innovations matrix) in the state equation?

Comment: I am speaking of a non-zero initial covariance matrix and a zero innovations covariance matrix.

Comment: Yes, I mean you should not use a zero evolution matrix for a constant state. You should use a small covariance. This is the recomendation of the aforementioned reference, If you have access to it, take a look at page 186.